# change screen size (Nougat)

Tags: android, display

our application always need high resolution. but sometime user use setting menu-> display -> display resolution change resolution.

we can check use adb shell wm size. if user change to low resolution. 
our service display has problem.

how to force change screen resolution use Android code?

Comment: _if user change to low resolution. our service display has problem._ That is why you should develop for different resolutions/screens to supporting them...

Answer (score 1):

```
public float targetRatio = 9f/16f; 

void Start()
{
  Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
  cam.aspect = targetRatio;
}
```